# How do I connect a Layout/view to a specific object in a getView() adapter method?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

As far as I understood the getView's purpose is to "give" the ListView (or other interface), the specific view, each time the adapter is "asked to".
I got the object by the position :

myItem = (myItem) getItem(position);

then I checked if the convertView is not null, and initialized a default layout:

```
        itemLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView;  

        if (itemLayout == null) {

             LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService
                        (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            itemLayout= (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate (R.layout.my_item,null);
        }
```

And now I want to make the connection between my item/object and its layout- or in other words: fill this layout's views with the values of this item.

How can I make it? Or did I understand the whole concept completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the ViewHolder pattern for Android ListView or use RecyclerView instead.